# npm command : Cannot find module 'buffer-shims'

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am using MacOS High Sierra(10.13.5).

When I run `npm` command, e.g. `npm -v`, I constantly get this error:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'buffer-shims'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:36:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I tried the [following solution](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12407), which I found after googling:

```
rm -r node_modules; rm package-lock.json; npm install
```

I succeeded at removing the node_modules folder, but I can't find a `package-lock.json` file and I still get the same error.

How do I resolve the npm error I am encountering?

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is still necessary, but for future reference: I encountered the same problem and was able to fix it.

What I did was just reinstall nodejs (11.1.0 at the time of writing) and then all npm commands were working again. I think for some odd reason the nodejs/npm install got fubar and kept on throwing the aforementioned errors.